# How to plot one line with two different colors in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
alist = [110,120,130]
blist = [150,170,190]

df1 = pd.Series(alist)
df2 = pd.Series(blist)

frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)


df3 = result.reset_index(drop=False)
df3.plot(y=0)
plt.show()
```

Is there any way I can plot this line but have "df1" in the color blue and "df2" in the color green and still keep them as the same line? My current plot looks like this:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fXc8.png)

Comment: plot them separatelly `df1.plot(... , color='red')`, `df2.plot(... , color='green')`. But it may need to get `axis` - `ax = plt.gca()` and use it in `plot(..., ax=ax)`

Comment: you may also put `df1` and `df2` in separated columns (with different indexes) and later run `df3.plot()` without parameters. And if you want the same indexes then `pd.concat(frames, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw ranges. But it may need `[2:]` instead of `[3:]`

```
df3.iloc[:3].plot(color='blue')
df3.iloc[2:].plot(color='green')
```

Result:

[image]

If you use `[3:]` then you get gap between lines:

[image]

---

Full working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alist = [110,120,130]
blist = [150,170,190]

df1 = pd.Series(alist)
df2 = pd.Series(blist)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)

df3.iloc[:3].plot(color='blue')
df3.iloc[2:].plot(color='green')
#df3.iloc[3:].plot(color='green')  # with gap

plt.show()
```